Finding a basis for an unknown-weights-and-balance puzzle?

I have a collection of unknown integer weights $w_1, \ldots, w_n$.  I have a balance which I can use to weigh some pile of weights against some other pile to see which is heavier. Suppose I've done $n$ such experiments with arbitrarily chosen piles, and noted the results. Suppose further that in all of the balance experiments I did, the piles were never equal—one side was always heavier.

Now I want to consider the space of all possible values of $\vec{w}$ that are compatible with those experimental results.

So far, I can prove that solutions are closed under positive (integer) multiples and under positive (integer) linear combinations. (This is because the problem is secretly a linear system of inequalities.)

And I can prove that if $\vec{w}_1$ is a solution, then so is $2\vec{w}_1 + [1, 0,0,\ldots,0]$. But solutions like these seem derivative—this one is fundamentally based on the simpler solution $\vec{w}_1$.


My question: how do I compute an exhaustive list of the simplest solutions, i.e. solutions that cannot be written as the sum of a strictly smaller solution and some nonnegative extra?  I'm looking for a sort of "basis" of the solution space.

As step number one, I'd recommend extending the question to positive rational numbers. You can convert any solution there to an integer one by just scaling up, so you don't add any undesirable solutions, and it comes with the benefit of being able to scale solutions by positive rationals instead of just integers.

It's an interesting idea, but extending it to rational numbers eliminates the existence of "simplest" solutions, which is what my question is about. (With rational coefficients, if P is any solution, it can always be further decomposed as P/2 + P/2)
